# Negative binomial probability mass function without assuming last trial is success

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Given *k* successes, I'm looking for the probability mass function for *n* the number of trials that occurred. Wikipedia and other sources give it as:

$ \Pr(X = n) =\binom{n-1}{k-1} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

I'm wondering why the coefficient is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and not $\binom{n}{k}$. If we know there are *k* successes, why are we figuring out how to arrange *k-1* of them?

If the answer is that we assume the last trial is a success, and that therefore there are only *k-1* successes to arrange over the remaining *n-1* trials, is there a different formula for the condition that the last trial isn't necessarily a success?

Answer (score 1):

The negative binomial does assume that the last observed value (when you stopped) is a success. 
This link might be helpful:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/distribution-of-number-of-bernoulli-trials-to-a-given-number-of-successes